# Border in text android not in text view and not shadow

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to find an effect in text view android just like the below image.

This is a textview with border in the text:
[image]

Can anyone suggest me something to get this effect.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You could use a font that has a similar effect and then use Typeface to apply it.

Comment: Other than the typeface, is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MagicTextView](http://qwerjk.com/magic-text) will do text outlines, amongst other things.

[image]

```
<com.qwerjk.better_text.MagicTextView
    xmlns:qwerjk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.qwerjk.better_text"
    android:textSize="78dp"
    android:textColor="#ff333333"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    qwerjk:strokeColor="#FFff0000"
    qwerjk:strokeJoinStyle="miter"
    qwerjk:strokeWidth="5"
    android:text="Magic" />
```

Note: I made this, and am posting more for the sake of future travelers than the OP. 
 It's borderline spam, but being on-topic, perhaps acceptable?

**source**https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10294290/edit